# Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that executes a number of commands. How do I make the shell script exit if any of the commands exit with a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Hard method: test the value of `$?` after every command.  Easy method: put `set -e` or `#!/bin/bash -e` at the top of your Bash script.

Answer (score 504, accepted):

After each command, the exit code can be found in the `$?` variable so you would have something like:

```
ls -al file.ext
rc=$?; if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then exit $rc; fi
```

You need to be careful of piped commands since the `$?` only gives you the return code of the last element in the pipe so, in the code:

```
ls -al file.ext | sed 's/^/xx: /"
```

will not return an error code if the file doesn't exist (since the `sed` part of the pipeline actually works, returning 0).

The `bash` shell actually provides an array which can assist in that case, that being `PIPESTATUS`. This array has one element for each of the pipeline components, that you can access individually like `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`:

```
pax> false | true ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
1
```

Note that this is getting you the result of the `false` command, not the entire pipeline. You can also get the entire list to process as you see fit:

```
pax> false | true | false; echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
1 0 1
```

If you wanted to get the largest error code from a pipeline, you could use something like:

```
true | true | false | true | false
rcs=${PIPESTATUS[*]}; rc=0; for i in ${rcs}; do rc=$(($i > $rc ? $i : $rc)); done
echo $rc
```

This goes through each of the `PIPESTATUS` elements in turn, storing it in `rc` if it was greater than the previous `rc` value.

Comment: Same feature in just one line of portable code:  `ls -al file.ext || exit $?` ( [[ ]] is not portable )

Comment: MarcH, I think you'll find that `[[ ]]` is pretty portable in `bash`, which is what the question is tagged :-) Strangely enough, `ls` doesn't work in `command.com` so it's not portable either, specious I know, but it's the same sort of argument you present.

Comment: I know this is ancient, but it should be noted that you can get the exit code of commands in a pipe via the array `PIPESTATUS` (i.e., `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` for the first command, `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` for the second, or `${PIPESTATUS[*]}` for a list of all exit stati.

Comment: It needs to be emphasized that elegant and idiomatic shell scripting very rarely needs to examine `$?` directly.  You usually want something like `if ls -al file.ext; then : nothing; else exit $?; fi` which of course like @MarcH says is equivalent to `ls -al file.ext || exit $?` but if the `then` or `else` clauses are somewhat more complex, it is more maintainable.

Comment: `[[ $rc != 0 ]]` will give you an `0: not found` or `1: not found` error.  This should be changed to `[ $rc -ne 0 ]`.  Also `rc=$?` could then be removed and just used `[ $? -ne 0 ]`.

Comment: @curtlee2002, you don't get that error in bash, which is the most likely shell. You only see that execution error if you omit the `[[`.

Comment: @DevSolar your comment was indeed very useful. thanks for posting it.

Comment: @CurtisLeeBolin you are on the right track, but actually, instead of `if [[ $rc != 0 ]];` or `if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]];` or any other `0` vs `1` test, do `if $(exit $rc);` Stop thinking "0 is true and 1 is false" because it leads to mistakes. What you really mean is "if command `exit`s without an error code, do A, if it `exit`s without an error code, do B." So, use `exit $code`.

Comment: @triplee Note that `cmd || exit $?` can be further shortened to `cmd || exit`, removing another explicit reference to $?

Comment: See also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: Simpler, still for BASH: `rc=$?; [[ $rc = 0 ]] || exit $rc`

Answer (score 225):

If you want to work with `$?`, you'll need to check it after each command, since `$?` is updated after each command exits.  This means that if you execute a pipeline, you'll only get the exit code of the last process in the pipeline.

Another approach is to do this:

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

If you put this at the top of the shell script, it looks like Bash will take care of this for you.  As a previous poster noted, "set -e" will cause Bash to exit with an error on any simple command.  "set -o pipefail" will cause Bash to exit with an error on any command in a pipeline as well.

See [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-scripting-problem-with-exit-codes-444852/) or [here](http://steve-parker.org/sh/exitcodes.shtml) for a little more discussion on this problem.  [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) is the Bash manual section on the `set` builtin.

Comment: This should really be the top answer: it's much, much easier to do this than it is to use `PIPESTATUS` and check exit codes everywhere.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash -e` is the only way to start a shell script.  You can always use things like `foo || handle_error $?` if you need to actually examine exit statuses.

Comment: @DavisHerring That's incorrect or misleading in several respects. The shell's `-e` option has some surprising corner cases, and its use is thus even discouraged in some guidelines, especially for beginners. And specifying it on the shebang line is brittle; putting `set -e` in the script itself is more robust.

Comment: @tripleee: I don’t know that “some guidelines” means that my own advice on the subject is “incorrect”.  Is your suggestion to use `set -e` based on running `bash …/foo` and losing the option?  If so, there are lots of ways to misrun a script if you choose to run it from the outside…

Comment: Quite so, but then by definition "the only way" is untrue. For example, the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script summarizes some advice which recommends against `set -e`.

Answer (score 54):

"`set -e`" is probably the easiest way to do this. Just put that before any commands in your program.

Comment: @SwaroopCH `set -e` your script will abort if any command in your script exit with error status and you didn't handle this error.

Comment: `set -e` is 100% equivalent to `set -o errexit` which unlike the former can be searched. Search for opengroup + errexit for official documentation.

Answer (score 31):

If you just call exit in Bash without any parameters, it will return the exit code of the last command. Combined with `OR`, Bash should only invoke exit, if the previous command fails. But I haven't tested this.

```
command1 || exit;
command2 || exit;
```

Bash will also store the exit code of the last command in the variable `$?`.

Answer (score 27):

```
[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit $?; # Exit for nonzero return code
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be ``exit $?`` (no parens)?

Comment: See also [Why is testing ”$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 21):

http://cfaj.freeshell.org/shell/cus-faq-2.html#11

11. How do I get the exit code of `cmd1` in `cmd1|cmd2`

    First, note that `cmd1` exit code could be non-zero and still don't mean an error. This happens for instance in

    ```
    cmd | head -1
    ```

    You might observe a 141 (or 269 with ksh93) exit status of `cmd1`, but it's because `cmd` was interrupted by a SIGPIPE signal when `head -1` terminated after having read one line.

    To know the exit status of the elements of a pipeline
    `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`

    a. with [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`):

    The exit codes are provided in the pipestatus special array.
    `cmd1` exit code is in `$pipestatus[1]`, `cmd3` exit code in
    `$pipestatus[3]`, so that `$?` is always the same as
    `$pipestatus[-1]`.

    b. with Bash:

    The exit codes are provided in the `PIPESTATUS` special array.
    `cmd1` exit code is in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`, `cmd3` exit code in
    `${PIPESTATUS[2]}`, so that `$?` is always the same as
    `${PIPESTATUS: -1}`.

    ...

    For more details see *[Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)*.

Comment: The first link is broken: *"We can’t connect to the server at cfaj.freeshell.org."*

Answer (score 19):

For Bash:

```
# This will trap any errors or commands with non-zero exit status
# by calling function catch_errors()
trap catch_errors ERR;

#
# ... the rest of the script goes here
#

function catch_errors() {
   # Do whatever on errors
   #
   #
   echo "script aborted, because of errors";
   exit 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't "exit 0", since that indicates success.

Comment: exit_code=$?;echo "script aborted, because of errors";exit $exit_code

Answer (score 11):

In Bash this is easy. Just tie them together with `&&`:

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

You can also use the nested *if* construct:

```
if command1
   then
       if command2
           then
               do_something
           else
               exit
       fi
   else
       exit
fi
```

Comment: +1 This was the simplest solution I was looking for. In addition, you can also write `if (! command)` if you expect a nonzero errorcode from command.

Comment: this is for sequencial commands.. what if i want to launch those 3 in parallel and kill everyone if any one of them fails?

Answer (score 4):

```
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# purpose: to run a command, log cmd output, exit on error
# usage:
# set -e; do_run_cmd_or_exit "$cmd" ; set +e
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
do_run_cmd_or_exit(){
    cmd="$@" ;

    do_log "DEBUG running cmd or exit: \"$cmd\""
    msg=$($cmd 2>&1)
    export exit_code=$?

    # If occurred during the execution, exit with error
    error_msg="Failed to run the command:
        \"$cmd\" with the output:
        \"$msg\" !!!"

    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ] ; then
        do_log "ERROR $msg"
        do_log "FATAL $msg"
        do_exit "$exit_code" "$error_msg"
    else
        # If no errors occurred, just log the message
        do_log "DEBUG : cmdoutput : \"$msg\""
    fi

}
```

Comment: There's rarely a reason to use `$*`; use `"$@"` instead to preserve spaces and wildcards.