# Can you access the code of an exit command in a trap?

Tags: bash

I understand that I can use $? to see the exit code of the last executed command, but what if I want to identify whether I have thrown my own "exit 0" or "exit 1"?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash -e    
trap "{ echo Exit code $?; exit; }" EXIT    
exit 1
```

If I run this script, it prints out "Exit code 0" and then exits with exit code 1. Can I access the code in the trap, or am I just going about this the wrong way? In other words, I would like this simple script to print out "Exit code 1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 0 because `$?` at the beginning of a script, where it is substituted due to the double quotes, is 0.

Try this instead:

```
trap '{ echo Exit code $?; exit; }' EXIT
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Very simple yet, so easy to overlook !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any process that terminates sets the `$?`, it means that it constantly will get overwritten. Save `$?` to a separately named var that is unique and echo that upon exit.

Edit

See [Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code)

Comment: I don't think this quite answers what I'm getting at. How would you change my script to incorporate your solution?

Comment: @Ben-Flynn Updated answer with link to SO post

Comment: I looked at that, and it would work if I called out to some command that returned with a failed exit code. It does not address what happens when I call "exit 1" myself from my script. As I mentioned, although I call "exit 1" the trap's $? show's 0, not 1. For now I decided to write my own failure function instead of calling exit, but I still would like to know if it's possible to capture the exit status that my own process is about to exit with in the trap.