# How is wait behaving in this script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo $? $?' SIGINT

for i in `seq 10`; do
  echo hello from for
  sleep 10
done &

bgproc=$!
echo bgproc is $bgproc
ps -o pid,ppid,cmd
echo "waiting now"
wait $bgproc
```

I do

```
kill -2 <pid>
```

and get

```
0 0
```

as o/p

Question:

When I send SIGINT to this script.

Why does it terminate ? I know its because of the wait statement at the end. But whats happening there ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you access the code of an exit command in a trap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176834/can-you-access-the-code-of-an-exit-command-in-a-trap)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate though. I am also asking how is wait command behaving here.

Comment: From bash beginner's guide page 139: "When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait built-in, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait built-in to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed."

Comment: Btw: using bash, you don't need to use an external command `seq` to write that kind of `for` loop : `for i in {1..10}`. Here's a [reminder about using command output in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607361/2900196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html):

> When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the `wait`
>   builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will
>   cause the `wait` builtin to return immediately with an exit status
>   greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.