# ffmpeg in a bash pipe

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a rmvb file path list, and want to convert this files to mp4 files. So I hope to use bash pipeline to handle it. The code is

```
Convert() {
    ffmpeg -i "$1" -vcodec mpeg4 -sameq -acodec aac -strict experimental "$1.mp4"
}

Convert_loop(){
    while read line; do
       Convert $line
    done
}

cat list.txt | Convert_loop
```

However, it only handle the first file and the pipe exits.

So, does ffmpeg affect the bash pipe?

Comment: I replaced the "smart" quotes in your question with regular ASCII quotes, since it didn't seem they were a source of your problem.

Comment: There is no `mpe4` codec. [`-sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524). Use `-qscale:v` with a value of 2 to 5 instead (lower is higher quality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveat: I've never used `ffmpeg`, but in working with other questions concerning the program, it appears that, like `ssh`, `ffmpeg` reads from standard input without actually using it, so the first call to `Convert` is consuming the rest of the file list after `read` gets the first line. Try this

```
Convert() {
    ffmpeg -i "$1" -vcodec mpe4 -sameq -acodec aac \
           -strict experimental "$1.mp4" < /dev/null
}
```

This way, `ffmpeg` will not "hijack" data from standard input intended for `read` command.

Answer (score 3):

> [...]
>
> ```
> for i in `cat list.txt`
> ```

Never use this syntax :

```
for i in $(command); do ...; done # or
for i in `command`; do ...; done
```

This syntax read the output of a command word by word and not row by row which often creates unexpected problems (like when row contain some spaces and when you want read a row like an item for example).

There always is a smarter solution :

```
command|while read -r; do ...; done # better general case to read command output in a loop
while read -r; do ...; done <<< "$(command)" # alternative to the previous solution
while read -r; do ...; done < <(command) # another alternative to the previous solution
for i in $DIR/*; do ...; done # instead of "for i in $(ls $DIR); do ...; done
for i in {1..10}; do ...; done # instead of "for i in $(seq 1 10); do ...; done
for (( i=1 ; i<=10 ; i++ )); do ...; done # such that the previous command
while read -r; do ...; done < file # instead of "cat file|while read -r; do ...; done"
while read -r || [[ -n $REPLY ]]; do ...; done < file # Same as before but also deal with files that doesn't have EOF.

# dealing with xargs or find -exec sometimes...
# ...
```

I wrote a course with more details about this subject and recurring errors, but in French, unfortunately :)

To answer the original question, you could use something like :

```
Convert() {
    ffmpeg -i “$1” -vcodec mpe4 -sameq -acodec aac -strict experimental “$1.mp4”
}

Convert_loop(){
   while read -r; do
       Convert $REPLY
   done < $1
}

Convert_loop list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience, and really good bash programming practice.

Comment: `for i in $(command)` is perfectly fine if you set `IFS` to only *newline* and *tabulator*, like so: `IFS=$'\n\t'` (which, along with `set -eu`, one should do in every shell script).  Also, `read` should **always** be used as `read -r`, or else it will interpret backslashes, and you're even worse off than with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Sigi Most of the time, people don't change the IFS for such kind of loop. Moreover, it's unnecessary given that other syntaxes based on `while` already work fine (see examples of my answer). Why change the behavior of a `for` loop to reproduce the behavior of the `while` loop ? We have to be pragmatic 
and use the tools that are best suited...

Comment: @Sigi However, for the use of `-r` I agree, and I've edited my answer ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann It is **much** less error prone to set `IFS` once at the beginning of the script, and then be able to rely on `for` loops, compared to having to use the `while read -r` construction all the time (which is awkward in itself **and** you have to remember `-r`). On the other hand, `for i in $(cmd)` is natural and easy. Also see http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html for a great article on this topic.

Comment: @Sigi It's a way of seeing things with which I'm not quite agree (I explained why and I don't think that `for` syntax is much easier than `while`). However, when we know what we do, I have nothing to complain about. I write that kind of answer when I see that the `for` loop is incorrectly used (and from my point of view, use incorrectly a `for` loop is worse than forgetting the `-r` option, but everything is relative).

Comment: @IdrissNeumann You were right in your objection with the `for` loop in this context, and you gave the right explanation for it.  However, I think it's wrong to then advise to "never, ever use it", when there is a great solution in form of the `IFS` trick (which is extremely useful if your filenames never contain `\n` or `\t`, i.e. in almost all cases).  Also, it should be obvious that `for i in $(cmd)` is easier than `while read -r` (because if it wasn't, the latter would be far more popular with novice script programmers).  Oh, and `for` + `IFS=$'\n\t'` is more solid than `while read -r`.

Answer (score 1):

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ! =)

```
convert() {
    ffmpeg -i "$1" \
           -vcodec mpe4 \
           -sameq -acodec aac \
           -strict experimental "${1%.*}.mp4"
}

while read line; do
    convert "$line"
done < list.txt
```