# bash: process substitution, paste and echo

Tags: bash, unix, stdout

I'm trying out process substitution and this is just a fun exercise.

I want to append the string "XXX" to all the values of 'ls':

```
paste -d ' ' <(ls -1) <(echo "XXX")
```

How come this does not work? XXX is not appended. However if I want to append the file name to itself such as

```
paste -d ' ' <(ls -1) <(ls -1)
```

it works.

I do not understand the behavior. Both echo and ls -1 write to stdout but echo's output isn't read by paste.

Comment: `echo` only produces a single line; `paste` needs one string for each line produced by `ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does it only for the first line, since it groups the first line from parameter 1 with the first line from parameter 2:

```
paste -d ' ' <(ls -1) <(echo "XXX")
```

... outputs:

```
/dir/file-a XXXX
/dir/file-b
/dir/file-c
```

... you have to:

```
for i in $( ls -1 ); do echo "$i XXXX"; done
```

Comment: If you want to use paste, you will need an array of as many elements initialized to "XXX", as files exist in the directory that you are listing. I think it is much simpler (even some may say than less elegant) to use a for iteration as in my answer above.

Comment: Never use `for i in $(command)`
See this answer for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361#19607361

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this, using a `printf` hack to display the file with zero length output and XXX appended.

```
paste -d ' ' <(ls -1) <(printf "%.0sXXX\n" *  )
```

Demo :

```
$ ls -1
filename1
filename10
filename2
filename3
filename4
filename5
filename6
filename7
filename8
filename9
```

Output :

```
filename1 XXX
filename10 XXX
filename2 XXX
filename3 XXX
filename4 XXX
filename5 XXX
filename6 XXX
filename7 XXX
filename8 XXX
filename9 XXX
```

If you just want to append XXX, this one will be simpler :

```
printf "%sXXX\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `XXX` after every line of `ls -l` output, you need a second command that output x times the string. You are echoing it just once and therefore it will get appended to the first line of `ls` output only.

If you are searching for a tiny command line to achieve the task you may use `sed`:

```
ls -l | sed -n 's/\(^.*\)$/\1 XXX/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's a funny one, not using any external command except the legendary `yes` command!

```
while read -u 4 head && read -u 5 tail ; do echo "$head $tail"; done 4< <(ls -1) 5< <(yes XXX)
```

(I'm only posting this because it's funny and it's actually not 100% off topic since it uses file descriptors and process substitutions)

Answer (score 1):

> ... you have to:
>
> ```
> for i in $( ls -1 ); do echo "$i XXXX"; done
> ```

Never use `for i in $(command)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607361/2900196) for more details.

So, to answer of this original question, you could simply use something like this :

```
for file in *; do echo "$file XXXX"; done
```

Another solution with awk :

```
ls -1|awk '{print $0" XXXX"}'
awk '{print $0" XXXX"}' <(ls -1) # with process substitution
```

Another solution with sed :

```
ls -1|sed "s/\(.*\)/\1 XXXX/g"
sed "s/\(.*\)/\1 XXXX/g" <(ls -1) # with process substitution
```

And useless solutions, just for fun :

```
while read; do echo "$REPLY XXXX"; done <<< "$(ls -1)"
ls -1|while read; do echo "$REPLY XXXX"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xargs for the same effect:

```
ls -1 | xargs -I{} echo {} XXX
```