# cant use commands `date` or `find` when executing a script via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've built a script for applying a patch to a server. It works great(ish) and makes backups of any files it overwrites using the `--backup=t` syntax. Now I need to move these backups as they are no longer ending `.php` but are ending instead `.php.~1~` which means if you view the file via a web browser you'd get the plain text output of the `php` script

I can *almost* do this when logged on to the webserver fine using the following command

```
for I in `sudo find /path/to/web/root -type f \( -name "*.*~1~" \)` ; do sudo mv $I ~/$I`date +%Y%m%d` ; done
```

There's a slight issue that the find command returns the fullpath to the file and as such `$I` needs truncating after it's been used in the mv, but that's another issue and outside the scope of this question

The problem I'm having is that when I try to execute this command remotely I get the following error

`find: command not found`

`date: command not found`

To address concerns raised about the output of `find` not being suitable to iterate over I knocked up this quick test

```
findtest lukes$ ls web
1   1.~1~   2   2.~1~   3   4   6   6.~1~   7   8   9
findtest lukes$ for I in `sudo find web -type f \( -name "*.*~1~" \)` ; do sudo mv $I $I`date +%Y%m%d` ; done
findtest lukes$ ls web
1       2       3       6       7       9
1.~1~20140201   2.~1~20140201   4       6.~1~20140201   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use this syntax :

```
for var in in `cmd`; do ... ; done
for var in in $(cmd); do ... ; done
```

See this [reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361?stw=2#19607361) for more details.

Otherwise, you don't have to use a loop to execute commands on each items returned by `find`.

```
find [...] -exec [commands] {} \;
```

Here is an example :

```
find /home/yourdir -name "*.txt" -exec cat {} \;
```

It's much better than :

```
for i in $(find /home/yourdir -name "*.txt"); do cat $i; done
```

Finally, could you give us the content of the following variables remotely ?

```
echo $PATH
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: Nice detailed post you've linked to but it seems to me the output of find will always tokensize the output into a list correctly

Comment: I've added a test that shows the output of find being used to loop fine.

Comment: I've added a little question in my post to debug your problem.

Comment: Thats sorted it, I'd mistakenly reassigned $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Could be there's very little environment set up for the user you're ssh'ing into the remote host as. PATH may not be set, for some reason.

Try using full paths to find and date:

```
for I in `sudo /bin/find /path/to/web/root -type f \( -name "*.*~1~" \)` ; do sudo mv $I ~/$I`/bin/date +%Y%m%d` ; done
```

I'd have thought that 'mv' would be not found too though if missing PATH was the case here.

Comment: I don't think it's the PATH as if I ssh into the web server as that user it works fine. I also tried looking up `which find ` and `which date` and tried specifying the fullpath like you've suggested.