# how to redirect output of CAT system call to variable and parse the varible data

Tags: linux, bash

my main intense is to to extract only user name from the`/etc/passwd` file and store then in array list i can display them one by one for this i have created simple script as below

```
#!/bin/bash


cat "/etc/passwd" > OUTPUT

echo -e $OUTPUT
IFS=:
read -ra ADDR <<< "$OUTPUT"

for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    echo -e $i
done
```

And the output of

```
>    cat /etc/passwd

   root:$1$L15vXdMd$SVx9qKAzHtLcqGN8n2SIc.:0:0:root:/:/bin/sh
   sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/bin/false
   super:x:1111:1100:Ldap user:/opt/www/usr/super:/bin/sh
   admin:x:1107:1100:Ldap user:/opt/www/usr/admin:/opt/www/jv/bin/cliInit.sh
   guest:x:1101:1100:Ldap user:/opt/www/usr/guest:/opt/www/jv/bin/cliInit.sh
   postgres:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/postgres:/bin/sh
   albert:x:1114:1100:Ldap user:/opt/wwwl/usr/albert:/opt/www/jv/bin/cliInit.sh
   ritesh112:x:1125:1001:RADIUS user:/opt/www/usr/ritesh112:/opt/dell/mc/bin/cliInit.sh
```

might be i am doing wrong way(that's why i ask the question) in above script.As per my logic first redirect the `/etc/passwd` to any variable by (`cat "/etc/passwd" > OUTPUT` don't know it right or wrong Also as alternative have tried `read -ra ADDR <<< "cat /etc/passwd"` but not working ) then separate the output by `IFS=:` bash variable and store all username in array `ADDR`.

i expect the output of script as follow except `sshd` and `postgres` user names.

```
root
super
admin
guest
albert
ritesh112
```

But it not working any one have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the output in an variable/array (you can get all sorts of buffering issues in some cases--although not with /etc/passwd, and there's simply no need), just do something like parsing it line by line or use a tool like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) or [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) as [perreal suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21523148/3076724)

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do 
  echo "${line%%:*}"
done < /etc/passwd
```

`${line%%:*}` will remove remove the longest suffix matching `:*`, meaning everything after and including the first `:`

**To get an array**, you can just change it to  (also note not including `postgres` and `sshd` in array. Number of ways to do this, but this should be good enough here)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  [[ "${line%%:*}" != postgres && "${line%%:*}" != sshd ]] && arr+=("${line%%:*}")
done < /etc/passwd

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
  echo -e "$i"
done
```

Or do something like command substitution (but again, not the best practice in most cases)

```
IFS=$'\n'
arr=($(< /etc/passwd))
```

Comment: ok that's true but it parse usrname for only display purpose but what i require later i interested to use array of user name list.

Comment: ohh..great but please except `sshd` and `postgres` username from array list so my job will done.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat "/etc/passwd" > OUTPUT
```

Does not create a variable, it just copies the `/etc/passwd` to a file named `OUTPUT`. To get the contents into a variable you can try `OUTPUT=$(cat /etc/passwd)`.

But you can simply use cut:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like :

```
declare -a array
i=0
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd|egrep -v "^(sshd|postgres)$"|while read; do
    array[$i]="$REPLY"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Or something like :

```
declare -a array
i=0
while read; do
    array[$i]="$REPLY"
    i=$((i + 1))
done <<< "$(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd|egrep -v '^(sshd|postgres)$')"
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Or :

```
declare -a array
i=0
while read; do
    array[$i]="$REPLY"
    i=$((i + 1))
done < <(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd|egrep -v '^(sshd|postgres)$')
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Otherwise, you could use awk too instead of `cut` and `egrep` (the both) :

```
awk -F":" '($1 != "sshd" && $1 != "postgres"){print $1}' /etc/passwd|while read; do
    #...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As nobody else seems to be putting the results in an array like you asked, I'll offer this:

```
declare -a array=($(awk -F: '!/^sshd|^postgres/{print $1}' /etc/passwd))
echo ${array[1]}
root
echo ${array[2]}
daemon
```

Comment: `echo ${array[1]}` not display anything!

Comment: Please copy and try again

Answer (score 1):

With a little of awk, you can reach your goal with

```
i=0
awk -F:  '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd | egrep -v '^(sshd|postgres)$' |while read; do
    array[i]=$REPLY
    i=$((i + 1))
done

#output 5th item in array 
echo ${array[4]}
#output array length
echo ${#array[*]}
```

Comment: thanks for help...it also display `sshd` and `postgres` which not require and also how to store list of users in array

Comment: Never use `for i in $(cmd)`. You could see this answer for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361?stw=2#19607361

And using `cut` instead of `awk` is enough in this case (no need to use a tank to kill a fly).

Answer (score 1):

@perreal already explained what's wrong with your script. Here is what I would do:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | egrep -v '^(sshd|postgres)$'
```

Explanation:

`cut` prints fields of the input. `-d:` says fields are delimited with `:`, `-f1` selects the first field.

`egrep` filters the output of `cut` further. `-v` says "print anything that doesn't match" and the regular expression matches exactly two user names. So it would still print `sshd2` or `postgresadmin`.

To put everything into an array:

```
declare -a array=($(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | egrep -v '^(sshd|postgres)$'))
```

(note: BASH syntax; other shells work slightly different).