# How to batch convert using ffmpeg from command line

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have this nice one-liner to merge an image & sound and create a video:

```
ffmpeg -i AlbumCover.png -i AnglersTunnel.flac AnglersTunnel.flv
```

I have an entire folder filled with other sounds I want to process in the exact same way. How can I perform this one-liner on my entire folder? There is only 1 image file to use for every sound file. the output video file name should be the same as the audio file name.

[image: My Folder]

Comment: You mentioned the folder with other sounds.  What about the image file and the name of the output file?  Is there a way to determine those based on the name of the sound file?  For example, will the output video file always use the base name of the sound file with a different extension?

Comment: there is only 1 image file to use for every sound file. the output video file name should be the same as the audio file name.

Comment: Ok - that's crucial.  You should update your question with that info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ffmpeg in a bash pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in *.flac; do
  ffmpeg -i AlbumCover.png -i "$i" "${i%%.*}.flv"
done
```

Comment: This is bash, not batch.

Comment: this worked wonderful, except it only converted files without spaces. can you help?

Comment: Oh dear, I just noticed the bash tag... @ThomasBuckler! The batch-file tag is _exclusively_ for Windows batch files! Now I've gone and downvoted a correct answer. Good. Job.

Comment: I updated the answer.  Try it with quotes around the filenames.

Comment: Consider adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option if the default encoder for FLV container format is libx264; otherwise a "better" but less compatible pixel format may be used. You can ignore this option if the crappy, old encoder named flv1 is used instead.

Comment: Also you should add `-loop 1` as an input option with `-shortest` as an output option. Without `-loop 1` the then video will contain a single frame which may not properly decode with some players.