# how to apply a working ffmpeg statement to a folder of .flacs

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Here is my beautifully working statement:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i AlbumCover.png -i AnglersTunnel.flac -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest AnglersTunnel.mp4
```

Now i want to run this on a folder of about 200 different .flac files with different names. Needing to use the same 'AlbumCover.png' image for every mp4 that is generated. I don't want to type in every different .flac file name by hand. How can i loop this? Additionally I need the name of the outputted mp4 file to be the same name as the .flac file that was converted.

Comment: How is this question different from your other recent question [How to batch convert using ffmpeg from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27748899/1109017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through all .flac files, replacing the .flac suffix with .mp4 like this:

```
for input in *.flac; do
    output=${input%.flac}.mp4
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i AlbumCover.png -i "$input" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest "$output"
done
```

`${input%.flac}` removes `.flac` from the end of the file name.

Comment: All the .flac files have different names. Some have spaces in the names. that's helpful but i need the output file name to be the same name as the .flac it was converted from.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *flac; do
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i AlbumCover.png -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest "${i%.flac}.mp4"
done
```

This is a simple `for` loop and the use of bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: that's helpful but i need the output file name to be the same name as the .flac it was converted from.

Answer (score 0):

My way is typically to escape spaces with the magic `$'\n'` variable:

```
IFS=$'\n'; 
for i in `find . -iname '*flac'`; do 
  ffmpeg -loop 1 -i AlbumCover.png -i "%" -c:v libx264 -tune \
  stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -shortest "$(echo "$i" | sed s/\.flac$/.mp4/)"
done
```

finds all your flac files ( recursively ), and then executes the subshell to replace `.flac` with `.mp4` in each filename. This subshell executes as part of the `-c` command.

I have a ffmpeg mocked up ffmpeg[1] that seems to verify the parameters are correctly escaped for the ffmpeg command:

```
["-loop", "1", "-i", "AlbumCover.png", "-i", "%", "-c:v", "libx264", "-tune", "stillimage", "-c:a", "aac", "-strict", "experimental", "-b:a", "192k", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-shortest", "./File 1.mp4"]
```

`for` loops are probably the single most useful flow control statement in bash, but for this kind of thing I'd steer towards `find` and `xargs`, which both support separating arguments with the `\0` character rather than something that might exist in pesky filenames, such as spaces, newlines, and so on.

Assuming all the flacs are in your home directory, then:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.flac' -print0 | \
xargs -0 -I % bash -c \
'ffmpeg -loop 1 -i AlbumCover.png -i "%" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest "$(echo "%" | sed s/\.flac$/.mp4/)"'
```

We're

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.flac' -print0 | xargs -0 -I % bash -c 'ffmpeg -loop 1 -i AlbumCover.png -i "%" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest "$(echo "%" | sed s/\.flac$/.mp4/)"'
["-loop", "1", "-i", "AlbumCover.png", "-i", "./File 1.flac", "-c:v", "libx264", "-tune", "stillimage", "-c:a", "aac", "-strict", "experimental", "-b:a", "192k", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-shortest", "./File 1.mp4"]
["-loop", "1", "-i", "AlbumCover.png", "-i", "./File 10.flac", "-c:v", "libx264", "-tune", "stillimage", "-c:a", "aac", "-strict", "experimental", "-b:a", "192k", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-shortest", "./File 10.mp4"]
["-loop", "1", "-i", "AlbumCover.png", "-i", "./File 2.flac", "-c:v", "libx264", "-tune", "stillimage", "-c:a", "aac", "-strict", "experimental", "-b:a", "192k", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-shortest", "./File 2.mp4"]
...
```

In this case, the single quotes escape the entire command nicely.  Bash is invoked because we need a subshell to run *after* `xargs` has done its replacement.  And the combination of `find`'s `-print0` and `xarg`'s `-0` escapes every valid filename.  I do, however, assume that the filename doesn't contain any quotes.

[1]

```
$ cat `which ffmpeg`
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts ARGV.inspect
```