# Combine for loop with cat and json2html

Tags: html, json, ruby, bash, html-table

I try to convert json files to html files. So I can later import them to the website. My idea is run [json2table](https://github.com/codeexpress/json2table) to create a table and write then to the html directory. But I find not out how can redirecting the output of json2table.

```
for file in $(ls json/*.json); do cat $file | json2table > html/$file.html; done
```

But this end with

```
bash: html/json/26.json.html: No such file or directory
```

Is there someone which can help to fix the error? Thank you

Silvio

Comment: Check content of `$file` and `html/$file.html` in your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `${file}` includes the `json` directory. When you don't have a directory `html/json` the redirection will fail.
I think you have a subdir `html` and stripping the path from `${file}` will work:

```
for file in json/*.json; do 
   cat "${file}" | json2table > html/"${file#*/}".html
   # OR avoid cat with
   # json2table < "${file}" > html/"${file#*/}".html
done
```

As a bonus I removed the `ls`, added quotes for filenames with spaces and showed in a comment how to avoid `cat`.

Comment: I suggest to replace `${file%/*}` with `${file#*/}`.

Comment: @Cyrus Good idea, tx.

Comment: +1 for removing `ls` but I think he needs to use something like `"$(basename $file)"` instead of `${file#*/}` to get the filename only. Otherwise that's will try to create some files with `html/json/{filename}.html` insteaf of `html/{filename}.html` as path.

Comment: `file=json/example.json; echo "${file#*/}" ` will return `example.json`.
The `file` returned by `json/*.json` will have one slash, never two. You might want to replace all `json` with `cat "${file} | json2table > "${file//json/html}"`, but this will fail for `json/json_in_basename.json`.
notpossible/example.json

Comment: Indeed, I tried with a subdir `json` and it works with this loop. I think it remain a lot more safer to use `basename` (which is a builtin in bash) to get the filename only. Anyway, I've given +1 to this answer :p

Comment: Thank you this is the solution. Thank you and thx for the ls information. This was new. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I want give all the complete script if people have same problem / project or how will call it.

The first loop generates an HTML table from the JSON files and stores it in an HTML file. The second loop combines the result of the first loop with a template, so that you have a complete page. In the body tag, the include is simply searched for, deleted and filled with the table.

```
#!/bin/bash

jdata="json"
hdata="html" 
template="tpl/tpl.html"
tmp="tmp"

# convert json to html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126226/combine-for-loop-with-cat-and-json2html/51126732#51126732

for file in $jdata/*.json;
do
    # php
    #php json.php $file > tmp/${file#*/}.html

    # ruby
    json2table < "${file}" > $hdata/"${file#*/}".html
done

# write html file 
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker

for file in html/*.html;
do
    # extract Project Number for newfile 
    filename="$(basename -- "$file")"
    extension="${filename#*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"

    # save the project number
    NO="$(grep "No" $jdata/$filename | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
    OUT="$NO.html"

    # write new html file
    sed 's/include/$x/g' tpl/tpl.html | x="$(<$file)" envsubst '$x' > html/$OUT

done
```

Thank you for help & Nice day
Silvio

Answer (score -1):

Your ls command returns the directory as well as the file name.

Ex. json/1.json json/2.json json/3.json

So do:

```
for file in $(/bin/ls json/*.json)
do
    cat $file | json2table >html/$(basename $file).html
done
```

- I always use the full path for `ls` in such conditions since I want to make sure I do not use any alias that might have been defined on it.
- basename removes the directory out of $file

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `ls` in a `for` loop like that. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607361/2900196).