# Split string with for loop and sed in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have following string in a variable:

`-rw-r--r-- 0 1068 1001 4870 Dec 6 11:58 1.zip -rw-r--r-- 0 1068 1001 20246 Dec 6 11:59 10.zip`

I'm trying to loop over this string with a for loop and get the following result:

```
Dec 6 11:58 1.zip
Dec 6 11:59 10.zip
```

Does anyone have the proper sed command to do this?

---

So let me make my question a little more clear. I do an `sftp` command with `-b` file and in there I do an `ls -l *.zip`. The result of this goes into a file. At first, I used a `sed` command to clear the first 2 lines since these are irrelevant information for me. I now only have the `ls` results, but they are on one line. In my example, there were just 2 zip files but there can be a lot more.

```
 ListOfFiles=$(sed '1,2d' $LstFile) #delete first 2 lines
    for line in $ListOfFiles
    do
        $line=$(echo "${line}" | sed (here i want the command to ony print zip file and date)
    done
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is not recommended with awk or sed.

Comment: Is the string really one line as shown, or is there a newline in the middle but `echo $variable` shows the line flat as in the question?  (Does `echo "$variable"` change the output?) . Is using `awk` an option?

Comment: Maybe use `stat` to get proper output instead of parsing `ls`.

Comment: to follow on the above comments, edit  your Q to show how the `variable` was created, ie `var=$(/bin/ls -l *.zip)` ? Good luck.

Comment: Problem is that i have to get this data from an sftp, with limited commands, i don't have stat, and i really need a date aswell, so ls -l is the only option i have

Comment: By the way, you really should avoid the `for i in $(command)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607361/2900196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Notes on the revised scenario

The question has been modified to include a shell fragment:

> ```
> ListOfFiles=$(sed '1,2d' $LstFile) #delete first 2 lines
> for line in $ListOfFiles
> do
>     $line=$(echo "${line}" | sed # I want to print only file name and date
> done
> ```

Saving the results into a variable, as in the first line, is simply the wrong way to deal with it.  You can use a simple adaptation of the code in my original answer (below) to achieve your requirement simply — very simply using `awk`, but it is possible using `sed` with a simple adaptation of the original code, if you're hung up on using `sed`.

**`awk` variant**

```
awk 'NR <= 2 { next } { print $6, $7, $8, $9 }' $LstFile
```

The `NR <= 2 { next }` portion skips the first two lines; the rest is unchanged, except that the data source is the list file you downloaded.

**`sed` variant**

```
sed -nE -e '1,2d' -e 's/^([^ ]+[ ]+){5}([^ ]+([ ]+[^ ]+){3})$/\2/p' $LstFile
```

In practice, the `1,2d` command is unlikely to be necessary, but it is safer to use it, just in case one of the first two lines has 9 fields.  (Yes, I could avoid using the `-e` option twice — no, I prefer to have separate commands in separate options; it makes it easier to read IMO.)

#### An answer for the original question

If you treat this as an exercise in string manipulation (disregarding legitimate caveats about trying to [parse the output from `ls` reliably](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)), then you don't need `sed`.  In fact, `sed` is almost definitely the wrong tool for the job — `awk` would be a better choice — but the shell alone could be used.  For example, assuming the data is in the string `$variable`, you could use:

```
set -- $variable
echo  $6  $7  $8  $9
echo $15 $16 $17 $18
```

This gives you 18 positional parameters and prints the 8 you're interested in.  Using `awk`, you might use:

```
echo $variable | awk '{ print $6, $7, $8, $9; print $15, $16, $17, $18 }'
```

Both these automatically split a string at spaces and allow you to reference the split elements with numbers.  Using `sed`, you don't get that automatic splitting, which makes the job extremely cumbersome.

Suppose the variable actually holds two lines, so:

```
echo "$variable"
```

reports:

```
-rw-r--r-- 0 1068 1001  4870 Dec 6 11:58 1.zip
-rw-r--r-- 0 1068 1001 20246 Dec 6 11:59 10.zip
```

The code above assumed that the contents of `$variable` was a single line (though it would work unchanged if the variable contained two lines), but the code below assumes that it contains two lines.  In fact, the code below would work if `$variable` contained many lines, whereas the `set` and `awk` versions are tied to '18 fields in the input'.

Assuming that the `-E` option to `sed` enables extended regular expressions, then you could use:

```
variable="-rw-r--r-- 0 1068 1001  4870 Dec 6 11:58 1.zip
-rw-r--r-- 0 1068 1001 20246 Dec 6 11:59 10.zip"
echo "$variable" |
sed -nE 's/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){5}([^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){3})$/\2/p'
```

That looks for a sequence of not white space characters followed by a sequence of white space characters, repeated 5 times, followed by a sequence of not white space characters and 3 sets of a sequence of white space followed by a sequence of not white space.  The grouping parentheses — thus picking out fields 1-5 into `\1` (which is ignored), and fields 6-9 into `\2` (which is preserved), and then prints the result.  If you decide you can assume no tabs etc, you can simplify the `sed` command to:

```
echo "$variable" | sed -nE 's/^([^ ]+[ ]+){5}([^ ]+([ ]+[^ ]+){3})$/\2/p'
```

Both of those produce the output:

```
Dec 6 11:58 1.zip
Dec 6 11:59 10.zip
```

Dealing with the single line variant of the input is excruciating — sufficiently so that I'm not going to show it.

Note that with the two-line value in `$variable`, the `awk` version could become:

```
echo "$variable" | awk '{ print $6, $7, $8, $9 }'
```

This will also handle an arbitrary number of lines.

Note how it is crucial to understand the difference between `echo $variable` and `echo "$variable"`. The first treats all white space sequences as equivalent to a single blank but the other preserves the internal spacing.  And capturing output such as with:

```
variable=$(ls -l 1*.zip)
```

preserves the spacing (especially the newline) in the assignment (see [Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable)).  Thus there's a moderate chance that the `sed` shown would work for you, but it isn't certain because you didn't answer clarifications sought before this answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

as others said you shouldn't really be parsing `ls` output.. Otherwise a dummy way to do it using awk to print out the columns you're interested in :

```
awk '{print $6, $7, $8, $9 "\n" $15, $16, $17, $18}' <<< $your_variable
```