# How to evaluate results of pipes in a bash script

Tags: bash, pipe, kill

I need help for the following problem:
I'd like to kill all instances of a program, let's say xpdf.
At the prompt the following works as intended:

```
$ ps -e | grep xpdf | sed -n -e "s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]\{1,\}.*$/\1/p" | xargs kill -SIGTERM
```

(the sed-step is required to extract the PID).

However, there might be the case that no xpdf-process is running. Then it would be difficult, to embed the line into a script, because it aborts after it immediately with a message from kill. What can I do about it?

I tried (in a script)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
set -x
test=""
echo "test = < $test >"
test=`ps -e | grep xpdf | sed -n -e "s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]\{1,\}.*$/\1/p"`
echo "test = < $test >"
if [ -z "$test" ]; then echo "xpdf läuft nicht";
else echo "$test" | xargs -d" " kill -SIGTERM
fi
```

When running the script above I get

```
$ Kill_ps
+ test=
+ echo 'test = <  >'
test = <  >
++ ps -e
++ grep xpdf
++ sed -n -e 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]\{1,\}.*$/\1/p'
+ test='21538
24654
24804
24805'
+ echo 'test = < 21538
24654
24804
24805 >'
test = < 21538
24654
24804
24805 >
+ '[' -z '21538
24654
24804
24805' ']'
+ xargs '-d ' kill -SIGTERM
+ echo '21538
24654
24804
24805'
kill: failed to parse argument: '21538
24654
24804
24805
```

Some unexpected happens: In test there are more PIDs then processes

At the prompt:

```
$ ps -e | grep xpd
21538 pts/3    00:00:00 xpdf.real
24654 pts/2    00:00:00 xpdf.real
```

When running the script again, the 24* PIDs change.

So here are my questions:

1. Where do the additional PIDs come from?
2. What can I do to handle the situation, in which no process I want to kill is running (or why does xargs not accept `echo "$test"` as input)? (I want my script not to be aborted)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `xargs -r kill -SIGTERM`? `xargs -r`: `--no-run-if-empty`. BTW, why are you not using [`killall`](https://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?section=0&os=Linux&query=killall)/[`pkill`](https://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?section=0&os=Linux&query=pkill) instead? Any complications there?

Comment: One additional pid comes from your `grep` command, which has the term `xpdf`. Your script will work (not optimal) if you use `xargs -n 1 kill -TERM`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer is for the case where `killall` or `pkill` (suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507625/2900196)) are not enough for you. For example if you really want to print `"xpdf läuft nicht"` if there is no pid to kill or applying `kill -SIGTERM` because you want to be sure of the signal you send to your pids or whatever.

You could use a bash loop instead of `xargs` and `sed`. It's pretty simple to iterate over CSV/column outputs:

```
count=0
while read -r uid pid ppid trash; do
  kill -SIGTERM $pid
  (( count++ ))
done < <(ps -ef|grep xpdf)
[[ $count -le 0 ]] && echo "xpdf läuft nicht"
```

There is a quicker way using `pgrep` (the previous one was for illustrate how to iterate over column-based outputs of commands with bash):

```
count=0
while read -r; do
  kill -SIGTERM $REPLY
  (( count++ ))
done < <(pgrep xpdf)
[[ $count -le 0 ]] && echo "xpdf läuft nicht"
```

If you're version of `xargs` can provide you the `--no-run-if-empty` you can still use it with `pgrep` (like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507625/2900196)), but it's not available on the BSD or POSIX version. It is my case on macOS for example...

`awk` could also do the trick (with only one command after the pipe):

```
ps -ef|awk 'BEGIN {c="0"} {if($0 ~ "xpdf" && !($0 ~ "awk")){c++; system("kill -SIGTERM "$2)}} END {if(c <= 0){print "xpdf läuft nicht"}}'
```

Comment: @GIC glad I could help. If your problem is solved, do not hesitate to pick the answer you want and mark at solved.

Comment: A slight corrigendum: while opens a subshell, so count =0 after the while loop (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/while-loop-subshell-dilemma-in-bash). So, that part does not work

Comment: @GIC Yes, you perfectly right. So I've updated my answer with another way to loop (with `while read`) over a command output without opening a subshell. You can keep `cmd|while read` if you don't need to keep the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pkill(1)`](https://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?section=0&os=Linux&query=pkill) or [`killall(1)`](https://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?section=0&os=Linux&query=killall) instead of parsing `ps` output. (Parsing human-readable output for scripting is not recommended. [This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is an example.)

Usage:

```
 pkill xpdf
 killall xpdf # Note that on solaris, it kills all the processes that you can kill. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252349#comment435182_252356
 pgrep xpdf # Lists pids
 ps -C xpdf -o pid=  # Lists pids
```

Note that tools like `pkill`, `killall`, `pgrep` will perform similar to `ps -e | grep`. So, if you do a `pkill sh`, it will try to kill `sh`, `bash`, `ssh` etc, since they all match the pattern.

But to answer your question about skipping xargs from running when there is nothing on the input, you can use `-r` option for (GNU) `xargs`.

```
   -r, --no-run-if-empty
          If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.
          Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.
          This option is a GNU extension.
```

Comment: When we put `ls` aside, what is not recommended is to iterate over an output of command that could contains spaces with a `for i in $(cmd)` loop. However `cmd|while read -r` or `awk` are perfectly fine and optimized for parsing column based or CSV outputs. I've wrote about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607361/2900196

Comment: BTW, I agree for using `killall` or `pkill` for this case

Comment: And POSIX `xargs` doesn't provide a `--no-run-if-empty` extensions so I'll keep my own answer just in case :)

Comment: And as I said in the answer, `-r` is a GNU extension. FWIW, I did not downvote your answer. So, feel free to not delete it.

Comment: Avoid parsing when direct tools are available. Also, the output of `cmd` must be reliable and not hackable. e.g. in the case of  `ps`, I don't know if the non-printable characters in the process name are ALWAYS printed as `?` or It is just `ps` installed on my system. Also, I have seen the `ps` output columns to be different on some "non-standard" unix-like distros (cough vmware cough). So, I try not to rely on such parsing.

Comment: @anishane Most of time using `ps -ef` is pretty the same output on BSD based systems and GNU systems. But yes, gnu/linux users have sometimes the bad habbit to use `ps aux` instead. I understand your point of using the right tool when it exists though but I just reacted on the statement "Parsing human-readable output for scripting is not recommended."... not always :) )

Comment: Warning: on some OSes, `killall` kills processes matching the specified command, but on [some it kills *all* processes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54764/killall-1m.html) (normally used as part of system shutdown). Be sure you [know which type of system you're on before using it](https://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/admin-mistakes-solaris-killall/).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yes. I just realized after posting the answer. I will update it.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann, I meant, try to make a habit of finding the right tool, before you use such a long pipeline for the job. Especially, don't try to parse human-readable output. I would not have said this if it were machine-readable output, like csv. I am saying this because I have done similar mistakes. Once I wanted to find the domain id of the VM running on xen. I did a long, non-robust pipeline to parse `xl list`; and a senior pointed me to `xl domid vmname`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please leave a comment for the reason. If I am following some bad coding practice, I can improve. Thank you.