# How to write a Git pre-commit hook that prevents committing of an Android project if the test project fails?

Tags: android, git, testing, hook, commit

Given that I in my workspace I have an android project `MyAndroidProject` and my tests project `MyAndroidProjectTests` directories how could I write a pre-commit git hook that will run the tests in the `MyAndroidProjectTests` and refuse to commit any code changes if the tests fail?

When I run tests on the terminal they usually have output like this:

```
com.mydomain.tests.Models.MyProjectTests:.......
Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=.......
Time: 0.05

OK (10 tests)
```

What I'm unsure about is how to what to use to try to determine if the tests passed or failed other than parsing the output of the last line (e.g. `OK` or `FAILED` and I'm not sure I like that method so much. I ideally I'd like a status to be returned from the command I use to run tests on the terminal:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.mydomain.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

I'd like to use the response in a shell script that I could place in the `.git/hooks/` folder as a pre-commit hook.

I would appreciate any info or links to other resources and much thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding long-running tasks in a pre-commit hook generally is a bad idea as it blocks you from working. Such checks should be done on a CI system that gates merges of commits that break tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git hooks are executed from your project/repo root - so you should be able to just use your command directly in a precommit hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb shell am instrument -w com.mydomain.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

if `adb` returns a none-zero exist code on failure - the commit will be aborted.

If you need to get the exit code for another purpose there are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code) indicating exactly how to do that.