# Needed assistance with checking the exit code returned by a node script in shell

Tags: shell

I had a script written in node.js which returns the appropriate exit code, either 0 for success and 1 for error. I am running this script in a shell script and need to compare the exit code to perform a few more operations, by using an if else block. Any suggestions how I can do that. I know we can use $? to get the exit code in shell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>See [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), particularly the `return_var` argument.</strike>

Apologies, I thought I saw a PHP tag.

Comment: but doesnt this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Excuse me, I thought I saw this tagged as [php]

Answer (score 0):

[Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code)

Thats the solution.

rc=$?

if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
    exit 2
fi