# Running a Python script within shell script - Check status

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, exit-code

Within my shell script I run this command:

```
python script.py
```

I was wondering, as a two part question:

1. How can I program my python script to pass a status back to the shell script that ran it depending on what happens in the python script. For example if something goes wrong in the python script have it exit with a code of 1 which is sent back to shell.
2. How can I get my shell script to read the exit code of python and exit for an error? For example, a status code of anything but 0 then exit.

Comment: For #2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code?rq=1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, you can pass the desired exit code as an argument to `sys.exit` in your python script.

Second, the exit code of the most recently exited process can be found in the `bash` parameter `$?`. However, you may not need to check it explicitly:

```
if python script.py; then
    echo "Exit code of 0, success"
else
    echo "Exit code of $?, failure"
fi
```

To check the exit code explicitly, you need to supply a conditional expression to the `if` statement:

```
python script.py
if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "failure: $?"
fi
```

Comment: Do I need a line before your code saying python script.py to run it?

Comment: The list of commands give in the `if` statement is executed, and its exit code determines which branch of the `if` is executed next.

Comment: I don't get how this works. To me this is saying "if script then" do this. Shouldn't it be "if script exit code = 0 then"

Comment: The `if` statement works a little differently in shell scripts than in other languages, due to their focus on running other programs. I'll update the answer to give an example of checking the exit code explicitly for contrast.

Answer (score 2):

Hate to resurrect a dinosaur but while this selected answer worked as written I wanted to add a variation where one can check against multiple exit codes. `$?` only seems to retrieve the exit code of the last executed program one time. So if you need to check the exit code against multiple cases, it is necessary to assign `$?` to a variable and then check the variable, a la (using @chepner 's example):

```sh
python script.py
exit_code=$?
if [[ $exit_code = 0 ]]; then
    echo "success"
elif [[ $exit_code = 1 ]]; then
    echo "a different form of success, maybe"
else
    echo "failure: $exit_code"
fi
```