# View exit code of a program (After the program exited)

Tags: linux, shell

Lets say a program that outputs a zero in case of success, or 1 in case of failure, like this:

```
main () {
    if (task_success())
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Similar with Python, if you execute exit(0) or exit(1) to indicate the result of running a script.  How do you know what the program outputs when you run it in shell.  I tried this:

```
./myprog 2> out
```

but I do not get the result in the file.

Comment: Use a print command in program.

Comment: Imagine you are a program. Your *output* is things you have said and written during your life. Your *exit code* is whether you go to heaven or to hell after you die.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between an `output` of a command, and the exit code of a command.

What you ran `./myprog 2> out` captures the [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) of the command and not the exit code as you showed above.

If you want to check the exit code of the a program in bash/shell you need to use the `$?` operator which captures the last command exit code.

For example:

```
./myprog 2> out
echo $?
```

Will give you the exit code of the command.

BTW,
For capturing the output of a command, you may need to use `1` as your redirect where `1` captures [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and `2` captures [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29).

Answer (score 0):

The returnvalue of a command is stored in `$?`. When you want to do something with the returncode, it is best to store it in a variable before you call another command. The other command will set a new returncode in `$?`.
In the next code the `echo` will reset the value of `$?`.

```
rm this_file_doesnt_exist
echo "First time $? displays the rm result"
echo "Second time $? displays the echo result"
rm this_file_doesnt_exist
returnvalue_rm=$?
echo "rm returned with ${returnvalue}"
echo "rm returned with ${returnvalue}"
```

When you are interested in stdout/stderr as well, you can redirect them to a file. You can also capture them in a shell variable and do something with it:

```
my_output=$(./myprog 2>&1)
returnvalue_myprog=$?
echo "Use double quotes when you want to show the ${my_output} in an echo."
case ${returnvalue_myprog} in
   0) echo "Finally my_prog is working"
      ;;
   1) echo "Retval 1, something you give in your program like input not found"
      ;;
   *) echo "Unexpected returnvalue ${returnvalue_myprog}, errors in output are:"
      echo "${my_output}" | grep -i "Error"
      ;;
esac
```