# run 2 rsync commands and print the output to a log file

Tags: bash, if-statement, boolean-expression, error-code

I'm new to scripting and would like to understand how to print out the variables based on boolean logic.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set variables
WEBAPPS_YES="Successfully synced webapps folder"
WEBAPPS_NO="Could not sync webapps folder"
RSYNC_YES="Successfully synced rsync log file"
RSYNC_NO="Could not sync rsync log file"

# Command to rsync 'webapps' folder and write to a log file
rsync -azvh ~/webapps -e ssh user@something.com:/home/directories >> /path/to/rsync.log 2>&1

# Command to rsync 'rsync.log' to a log file on backup server 'Larry'
rsync -azvh --delete ~/rsync.log -e ssh user@something.com:/path/to/logs

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
  echo 
  exit 0
else
  echo  >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I would like the whole `if`, `then`, `else` part to print out in the `echo` if both parts succeeded or not. I know I need some kind of logic statements but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the result after running each rsync command, and display the result afterwards. I think that would work:

```
# Command to rsync 'webapps' folder and write to a log file
rsync -azvh ~/webapps -e ssh user@something.com:/home/directories >> /path/to/rsync.log 2>&1
RESULT1="$?"

# Command to rsync 'rsync.log' to a log file on backup server 'Larry'
rsync -azvh --delete ~/rsync.log -e ssh user@something.com:/path/to/logs
RESULT2="$?"

if [ "$RESULT1" != "0" ]; then
    echo "$WEBAPPS_NO"
else
    echo "$WEBAPPS_YES"
fi

if [ "$RESULT2" != "0" ]; then
    echo "$RSYNC_NO"
else
    echo "$RSYNC_YES"
fi
```

Comment: That's a great idea! thanks! Would it be possible to print which one failed based on the variables above though? So I could have WEBAPPS_YES "but" RSYNC_NO. That kind of thing?

Comment: Sure, RESULT1 and RESULT2 will basically hold "0" is the command succeeded, so you can inspect that and display the result accordingly. See updated answer.

Comment: I'll give it a go and let you know. Thank you for the help

Comment: please explain this `rsync -azvh ~/webapps -e ssh user@something.com:/home/directories >> /path/to/rsync.log 2>&1
RESULT1="$?"` command.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, what part? The rsync flags are documented in the man page, and the rest is standard shell syntax.

Comment: Please this `>> /path/to/rsync.log 2>&1 RESULT1="$?"` part! Excuse my inexperience.

Comment: `2>&1` is to redirect both stdout and stderr to the log file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/876242/561309), and `RESULT1="$?"` is to the save the error code to the `RESULT1 variable` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/90435/561309)